# How to change Tab bar Icon dynamically when i passed between screens of stack inside in it

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to set tab bar icon dynamically. i have tab bar and each screen of tab bar is stack of screen. i want to change the tab bar icon when i am moving between screens inside of stack of that tab screen.

I have code in tab bar like following:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
    Invitations:{screen:invitationStack, 
    navigationOptions:() =>({
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor  }) => (
        <Econ name="users" style={{color:tintColor}} size={16} />
      ),
    })
  },
    Wishlist:{screen:wishListStack,
      navigationOptions:() =>({
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor  }) => (
          <Econ name="gift" style={{color:tintColor}} size={16} />
        ),
      })
    },
    " ":{screen:wishStack
  }, 
    Notifications:Notifications,
    Profile:{screen:profileStack,
      navigationOptions:() =>({
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor  }) => (
          <Econ name="user-circle" style={{color:tintColor}} size={16} />
        ),
      })
    }
}
```

and in my **wishStack.js**:

```
const wishStack = createStackNavigator({
  main1:WishList,
  addocassion:addocassion,
  savedwishlist:SavedWishlist,
  guest:AddWishListGuest,
  item:WishItem,
  occasion:AddWishOccasion,
  add2item:Add2Items
}
```

there is stack navigator.
I want to change tab bar icon when i moving from main1 to addocassion in stack.

Answer (score 0):

## try this code my issue was solved my that-

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/628

Comment: Hello, SO isn't a very good place for link only answers. Perhaps copy the most pertinent details from the webpage and include them here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers.